# Setting request body encoding in Postman

Tags: rest, character-encoding, httprequest, postman

Is there any way to set the request body encoding in Postman to something other than UTF-8? Seems that even if I set the content-type header with the charset specified like this:

`Content-Type: text/xml; charset=windows-1251`

I still get the body encoded with UTF-8.